# How do I set up an App Engine backend for a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to be able to send a small push message from a Python Google App Engine server to a Chrome Extension. From searching the web, my best bet seems to be Google Cloud Messaging. (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/cloudMessaging)

However, the documentation for the Chrome extension side of GCM (as opposed to the Android side of GCM) is very poor. I cannot figure out what Python code to include in my App Engine server in order to communicate with the Chrome Extension.

The only info I can find is on the page linked to above, which has the following description of sending messages from a server to an extension:

> 1. Your app or extension client should register a handler to receive the gcm.onMessage event.
> 2. When your server sends a message to the user, it specifies all of the registration IDs that are related to that user and passes the message to the GCM service.
> 3. GCM servers route the message to all instances of Chrome running apps or extensions with one of the registration IDs.
> 4. When the message arrives on the client, Chrome starts the app or extension, if it is not already running, and calls the registered handler to process the message.

The documentation makes no mention of how exactly the server can pass the message to the GCM service.

I'm hoping someone out there has figured out how to send push messages from an App Engine server to a Chrome Extension.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the "Chrome extensions side", that's your conceptual problem. You're looking at the wrong documentation.

You are looking to implement a GCM Server, and the documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html).

You can also search for sample code, for instance [this python GAE server](https://github.com/gregbayer/gae-python-gcm).

Comment: GCM can either send messages to a Chrome Extension or to an Android device. Both of the things you linked to refer to sending messages between a GCM server and Android. Eg "This application server sends data to a GCM-enabled Android application via the chosen GCM connection server" from the first link and "This module is designed to take care of everything you have to think about when working with Android GCM messages on the server" from the second.

Comment: There is no parcitcal difference. Either an Android client or a Chrome client requests a registration ID and then there is no difference for the server.

Comment: In fact, to explain this further: in the past Chrome had a separate cloud messaging API, but after a while this was introduced and the specific API died off. They are now merged into one. Chromium blog links: [\[1\]](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/04/simplifying-cloud-messaging-for-app.html) [\[2\]](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/09/moving-towards-single-cloud-messaging.html)

Comment: Ah, okay! I didn't realize that the Android and Chrome functionality had been merged. I'll give this a shot. Thanks, Xan!

Comment: So do I still send the POST request to "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" (as is mentioned in the docs: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) even though the destination is a Chrome Extension?

Comment: Yes, you should post to the same endpoint for both Android apps and Chrome extensions.